# Javascript code not executing in image tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, angular, laravel-8

This is my first time writing here. I want to display an image in an info window of google maps. After retrieving data from the database, i successfully displayed some data in the info window. But the problem is to display the image. 'clinics[i].image' is the one not executing.

```
infowindow.setContent('<div>' +
                        '<span>'+' <img src="{{ asset("storage/image/".'clinics[i].image') }}" style="height: 150px; width: 300px;"> '+ '</span><br>' +
                      '<span><h3> ' + clinics[i].name  + '('+clinics[i].type +')'+'</h3></span><br>' +
                       '<span>Hours: ' + clinics[i].hours + '</span><br>' +
                      '</div>');
```

Comment: Have you looked at [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for including variables in your HTML?

Comment: Is that code inside a `.blade.php` file? Anyway, you can't mix Blade/PHP and JS like that.

Comment: hi, welcome to stackoverflow piliran. what broombeer meant is that your `<img src="{{ asset("storage/image/".'clinics[i].image') }}" ...` will be printed on html as something like `<img src"http://localhost:8000/storage/image/clinics[i].image" ...`. the reason being blade templating is unaware of your index `i`. you should move `clinics[i].image` outside of your `{{ asset(...) }}` and concat them as js.